# Value NULL at 1 of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject android

Tags: android, json, listview

I am using a code that retrieves the value from `json` data . checks it and based on the value it makes a custom layout (3 different layout ) in single `listview` .

Initially it was working fine . suddently it throws the error " Value NULL at 1 of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject "

the variable `plates` contains value , but still shows NULL

HomeFragment.java[image]

```
private class GetList_default extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {
            Dialog dialog = new Dialog(getActivity());
            String jsonStr;
            ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> Local_newsList;

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
                Local_newsList=new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();



                // Showing progress dialog
                /*dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
                dialog.setContentView(R.layout._wait_dialog);
                dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(android.R.color.transparent);
                dialog.show();*/

            }

            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {

    if (NetworkCheck.isNetworkAvailable(getActivity()) == true) {

                    //Log.d("index count for array", params[0]);
                    if(Integer.parseInt(params[0])==0){
                        //Log.d("index count for array","Rweached");
                        newsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
                    }


                    // Creating service handler class instance
                    ServiceHandler sh = new ServiceHandler();

                    // Making a request to url and getting response
                    String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(All_link.HOME_DATA_URL + "/"+params[0]+"/"+ icount,
                            ServiceHandler.GET);

                    Log.d("Response: ", "> " + jsonStr);

                    if (jsonStr != null) {
                        try {
                            JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

                            // Getting JSON Array node
                            news = jsonObj.getJSONArray(All_link.TAG_NEWS);


                            err = jsonObj.getString(All_link.TAG_ERROR);
                            String more = jsonObj.getString(All_link.TAG_MORE);

                            Log.e("------>Error",String.valueOf(err));
                            Log.e("------>More",String.valueOf(more));
                            if(more.equals("0")){

                                load_more = 0;

                            }else{

                                load_more = 1;
                            }

                            // looping through All Contacts
                            for (int i = 0; i < news.length(); i++) {

                                JSONObject segments_list = news.getJSONObject(i);

                                for (int plates_count = 0; plates_count < segments_list
                                        .length(); plates_count++) {


                                    String plates = "";
                                    if (plates_count == 3) {
                                        plates = String.valueOf("banner_image");

                                        JSONObject segments_plates = segments_list
                                                .getJSONObject(plates);

                                        //String flag = "banner_image";
                                        String id = segments_plates
                                                .getString(All_link.TAG_BANNER_ID);
                                        String banner_no = segments_plates
                                                .getString(All_link.TAG_BANNER_NO);

                                        String banner_image;

                                        if(segments_plates.getString(All_link.TAG_BANNER_THUMB_URL)==""){

                                            banner_image = All_link.TAG_NO_IMAGE;
                                        }else{

                                            banner_image = segments_plates.getString(All_link.TAG_BANNER_THUMB_URL);
                                        }

                                        String banner_status = segments_plates
                                                .getString(All_link.TAG_BANNER_STATUS);


                                        // tmp hashmap for single news
                                        HashMap<String, String> news_hashmap = new HashMap<String, String>();

                                        // adding each child node to HashMap key =>
                                        // value
                                        news_hashmap.put(All_link.TAG_BANNER_ID, id);
                                        news_hashmap.put(All_link.TAG_BANNER_NO,
                                                banner_no);
                                        news_hashmap.put(All_link.TAG_BANNER_THUMB_URL,
                                                banner_image);
                                        news_hashmap.put(All_link.TAG_BANNER_STATUS,
                                                banner_status);
                                        /*news_hashmap
                                                .put(All_link.TAG_BANNER_FLAG, flag);*/

                                        // adding contact to contact list
                                        newsList.add(news_hashmap);
                                        addSeparatorItem();
                                    } else {
                                        plates = String.valueOf(plates_count + 1);

                                        JSONObject segments_plates = segments_list.getJSONObject(plates);

                                        if(segments_plates.getString(All_link.TAG_NEWS_TYPE).equals("2")){

                                            //type_of_news = segments_plates.getString(All_link.TAG_NEWS_TYPE);
                                            addSeparatorItem_for_live();
                                        }                                   

                                        String id = segments_plates.getString(All_link.TAG_ID);
                                        String news_title = segments_plates.getString(All_link.TAG_NEWS_TITLE);
                                        String news_desc = segments_plates.getString(All_link.TAG_DESC);
                                        String segment = segments_plates.getString(All_link.TAG_SEGMENT);
                                        String plate = segments_plates.getString(All_link.TAG_PLATE);

                                        String img ="";
                                        if(segments_plates.getString(All_link.TAG_THUMB_URL).equals("")){

                                            img = All_link.TAG_NO_IMAGE;

                                        }else{

                                            img = segments_plates.getString(All_link.TAG_THUMB_URL);
                                        }


                                        HashMap<String, String> news_hashmap = new HashMap<String, String>();

                                        // adding each child node to HashMap key =>
                                        // value
                                        news_hashmap.put(All_link.TAG_ID, id);
                                        news_hashmap.put(All_link.TAG_NEWS_TITLE, news_title);
                                        news_hashmap.put(All_link.TAG_DESC, news_desc);
                                        news_hashmap.put(All_link.TAG_SEGMENT, segment);
                                        news_hashmap.put(All_link.TAG_PLATE, plate);
                                        news_hashmap.put(All_link.TAG_THUMB_URL, img);
                                        //news_hashmap.put(All_link.TAG_BANNER_FLAG, flag);
                                        // adding contact to contact list
                                        newsList.add(news_hashmap);

                                        int val = 0;
                                        int val2 = 1;
                                        val = (Integer.parseInt(segment)%2)==0 ? val:val2;

                                        if((Integer.parseInt(segment)%2)!=0){
                                            Log.e("--->CHECKING ODD EVEN", String.valueOf(val));
                                            addSeparatorItem();
                                            addSeparatorItem_for_alternate();   
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    } else {
                        Log.e("ServiceHandler", "Couldn't get any data from the url");
                    }
                } else {
                    Log.e("Network Error", "Internet Connection Error");
                    error_flag = 1;
                    // error = "Internet Connection Error";

                }
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
                super.onPostExecute(result);




                if(error_flag==1){

                    listView.setVisibility(8);
                    main_error.setText("Internet Connection Error! Please check your network settings and try again");
                    main_error.setVisibility(0);
                    img_error.setVisibility(0);

                }else{

                    listView.setVisibility(0);
                    main_error.setText("");
                    main_error.setVisibility(8);
                    img_error.setVisibility(8);

                    int currentPosition = listView.getFirstVisiblePosition();

                    mAdapter = new MyCustomAdapter(getActivity(), newsList);
                    listView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
                     // Setting new scroll position
                    listView.setSelection(currentPosition);
                    //mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }



                // Dismiss the progress dialog
                if (dialog.isShowing())
                    dialog.dismiss();




                SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = getActivity().getSharedPreferences(All_link.MyPREFERENCES,
                        Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                sharedPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());

                //For Breaking News Setting
                if (sharedPrefs.getInt("prefswtch4", 1) == 1) {

                    if (All_link.GLOBAL_BREAKING_FLAG == 0) {

                        new getBreakingNews().execute();

                    }

                } 

                //For Location Setting
                if (sharedPrefs.getInt("prefswtch1", 1) == 1) {



                } else {



                }

                //For Ticker Setting
                if (sharedPrefs.getInt("prefswtch2", 1) == 1) {

                    new getTicker().execute();

                } else {

                    marque.setVisibility(8);

                }


            }

        }
```

[image]

Comment: there are plenty of questions similar to this one on StackOverflow, please take a look at these first. Otherwise, post your JSON code.

Comment: posted JSON code as image file..

Answer (score 1):

From the posted code:

```
plates = String.valueOf("banner_image");
JSONObject segments_plates = segments_list.getJSONObject(plates);
```

I'm pretty sure "banner_image" is not a valid JSON object, hence the error.

(You probably also should remove the useless `String.valueOf(String)`)

Comment: its shows error on line " JSONObject segments_plates = segments_list.getJSONObject(plates); " .. In the ELSE part

Comment: It's an upvote not an "acceptation". About your comment, same thing, a number is not a valid JSON object.